# How to perfectly override the window.navigator object - PhantomJs?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, navigator

I tried many ways before posting here, all the solutions caught by google analytics, I just want override platform property. you can see all my tries here - [code](https://github.com/kongaraju/rawbot/blob/master/rawbot.js).

What's the problem?

I can able to override the platform object, but google analytics catching, when I override I can see user user in realtime traffic but they are not coming as page views, so the solution I have is not a perfect one.

If I am trying without overriding the navigator object everything seems fine I can see realtime traffic plus pageviews.

Can someone please help me to override platform in navigator object.

Comment: so, overriding `window.navigator` is OK, but google analytics does not like it ? How is that a PhantomJS issue ?

Comment: @ThongKuah I am not saying its a bug or issue with phantomJs, I am asking whats the best way to override navigator without caught by google analytics.

Comment: Ah right, it wasn't entirely clear from your original question